# jQuery active menu issue

Tags: jquery

I have tried to implement this jQuery active menu code: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Auto-Selecting_Navigation

```
 $(function(){
   var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
   if ( path )
     $('#sidebar_content a[@href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
 });
```

but it does not seem to be adding the class: http://www.thecreativealliance.org/gallery/advertising-and-marketing?CategoryID=39196&cat=Promotions%20%26%20publicity

Any ideas?

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.addClass('selected')` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/)) and change the query: `#sidebar_content a[href="' + ...` (@ and $ aren't needed).

[JQuery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/) is highly recommended, to keep in mind the available methods.

Comment: Thanks Culebron. I get the following error in firebug: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@href$="gallery/education-and-knowledge"]